# how to make dashboard dynamic using google charts?

Tags: yii2, dashboard

I am using scotthuangzl\googlechart\GoogleChart to make dashboard.
I want it to be dynamic and draw a pie chart using count of my records.
but when I pass value using variable to piechart it does not show required output.

```
  $contacts = Contacts::find()->count();
         $companies = Companies::find()->count();
         $user = User::find()->count();

        use scotthuangzl\googlechart\GoogleChart;

        echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'PieChart',
            'data' => array(
                array('Task', 'Hours per Day'),
                array('companies', $companies),
                array('contacts', $contacts),
                array('user', $user),                   
            ),
```

and it gives output as=
[image]

it only shows small angle with gray color .. and dont know from where this "other" field came from..
can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: code looks good. According to example in repo.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package but maybe Google does it so if one of the values is much greater than the rest it shows the one and the rest as "other". I'm not sure why you don't see orange part though.

Comment: if I directly give value It shows proper pie chart...code... array('companies', 15),
                array('contacts', 8),
                array('user', 7),

Comment: then check `$contacts, $companies` data.

Comment: `count()` returns string try type cast. Ex. `(int) $contacts`.

Answer (score 0):

in Yii2 the count() return a "string"
please try to parse the result using   (int)

```
echo GoogleChart::widget(array('visualization' => 'PieChart',
        'data' => array(
            array('Task', 'Hours per Day'),
            array('companies', (int)$companies),
            array('contacts', (int)$contacts),
            array('user', (int)$user),                   
        ),
```